# After authentication of facebook login/pwd, I get a dialog box says "install/cancel" instead of "allow/don't allow" App permission.?

Tags: facebook, android-emulator

After following as per Facebook-sdk instructions for android app i get the dialog box saying install/cancel instead of allow/don't allow . I tried changing App id and used other user's credentials for logging too. But still i get an error:

Update:i tried changing an app setting develope.facebook.com->Application->Advanced->disabled enhanced auth dialog. still no resolution.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The text changes for various reasons; whether it's the first time the user is using that app or not for example - this is expected, there's about 5 or 6 possible button text combinations - i think install/cancel is the one seen for new installations